# Drupal Anonymous Users Hidden Fields on Webform not showing up on e-mail

Tags: drupal, token, anonymous, drupal-webform

I'm trying to capture the url of the webform.  For validated users, the code below works:
%server[SERVER_NAME]%server[REQUEST_URI]

For anonymous users, it does not.

From Post#7, I checked out this thread and tried the patch, but it did not work
http://drupal.org/node/781786

When I tried that fix, the hidden form text title even disappeared.

When a user is verified, the field shows up just fine. I need it to show when a user is anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality seems to be the way that the webform creators want it. There are some workarounds, including dynamically setting the values with javascript. Check out [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/605572).

Javascript fix from thread:

```
Drupal.Ajax.plugins.anypluginname = function(hook, args){
    switch (hook) {
        case 'submit': // after submit was pressed
            $('#edit-submitted--product-link').val(window.location); // I know ID of my field :)
            /*
                Anything you want here
           */
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```